# Слово "сачковать"

Tags: этимология

О безделье говорят "сачковать". А что это за слово, откуда оно пошло?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сачковать - вторично, от "сачок". "Сачками" называли тех, кто всеми правдами и неправдами избегает от общей работы. Возможно, с пионерских времен, где ловля бабочек (сачком!) была занятием весьма удобным для такого сачкизма. А может, и от одного вида пожилого профессора-энтомолога, застуканного за этим детским занятием. Ну как такого "сачком" не назвать? Кстати, было обыграно в одном фильме, никак вспомнить не могу название...

Добавлено для [[@Виктор1799](/users/895/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%801799)](/users/895/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%801799)
САЧОК, -чка, м. 1. Бездельник, лентяй, халтурщик; прогульщик. Ну ты сачок. Эй, сачки, работать! 2. Место, где собираются люди, у которых нет дел; часто о местах, где собираются, курят студенты в перерывах между занятиями, после занятий (напр. в 1-м гуманитарном корпусе МГУ есть «малый сачок» и «большой сачок»). ♦ Сачка давить — бездельничать.
Возм. через уг. «сачок» — мелкий воришка, беспризорник, несовершеннолетний, хулиган. Первоначально из языка моряков. С эпохи парусного флота и позднее «сачком» или «саком» ирон. называли на корабле подвесную койку (the hammock). «Сачка давить» значило «лежать, валяться в этой койке, увиливать от работы, когда остальная команда работает». В общем зн. — «бездельничать». Со временем назв. койки перешло и на самого человека, отлынивающего от работы.
(Елистратов)

Comment: Об этом слове (правда, без объяснения его происхождения) я нашел упоминания только в одном словаре: Н.П.Колесников, Е.А.Корнилов (оба - покойные профессора Ростовского госуниверситета)"Поле русской брани" (словарь бранных слов и выражений в русской литературе).- Ростов-на-Дону, 1996

Comment: У Елистратова есть все (см. текст ответа). Вот только верить ему особо не хочется.

Answer (score 3):

САЧКОВАТЬ

К происхождению слова "сачковать".

Сразу после войны в 1947–49 годах Советская Армия перешла на новый тип стрелкового оружия (СКС-45; АК-47 и РПД), разработанного под секретный тогда 7,62мм боевой патрон образца 1943 года. И во время учебных стрельб ни одна гильза этого секретного патрона не должна была быть потеряна. С этой целью применяли своеобразный улавливатель гильз, изготовляемый в воинских частях из подручных материалов. Это было простое устройство типа сачка для ловли бабочек, только гораздо большего размера ― диаметр обода сака 0,8–1,0 метра, с глубиной сака до 80 сантиметров. Материалом сака, или сачка, служила обычно марлевая ткань.

И вот при учебных стрельбах зазвучала команда, к примеру: "Сержант Петров и рядовой Иванов на огневой рубеж шагом марш! Петров стреляет, Иванов сачкует. Заряжай! Огонь!"

При этом Петров заряжал, целился по мишени и стрелял, а Иванов в это время держал сачок неподалеку от патронника и ловил при помощи этого сачка все вылетающие из патронника стреляные гильзы. Таким образом Петров заряжал, целился и стрелял, т. е. "работал", а Иванов "сачковал", или попросту был сачком.

Вот таким образом это армейского происхождения замечательное слово "сачок" пришло в сороковые годы двадцатого столетия и в наш быт.

И.П.Иванов, yevbaz@ro.ru

Answer (score 2):

Знаю другую версию.
"Сачкует" один из членов орудийного расчета - ловит трубки воспламенения при стрельбе из пушки.
Работа вроде бы несложная, но если сачок уронит раскаленную трубку, она упадёт вниз, к пороховым картузам, рассыпая искры.